# How to set JWT token with PHP on successful login?

Tags: login, rest-api

I'm creating a decoupled application: the frontend is built with React, the backend uses Wordpress. However, due to some limitations the login and registration frontend pages must use a Wordpress theme, so the user is redirected to the React app only after login.

In the React frontend, I need to assign the current user a JWT token so that they can make authenticated requests; so I have to set a JWT token when they log in from the Wordpress theme. Basically, I need to set the JWT token when I'm still in a PHP application.

I've read that you can do API requests in PHP with `curl` (which I've never used before), so my best bet right now is to hook into the `wp_login` action, and use the JWT Authentication plugin for Wordpress to make a request with `curl` to the endpoint that generates a token.

This solution feels a bit weird to me though. Can you think of a better one?

Comment: It's a little confusing about your app being "decoupled", but yet having the frontend use WordPress. If your app will live inside of WordPress, authentication is tracked with a cookie that is set up after logging in, and WP API requests that include a nonce can be authenticated requests without a JWT. If your app will live outside of WordPress, why are you having them log into it through the frontend form? You can do the initial auth through the API using that plugin you mentioned.

Comment: What you’re describing is essentially oauth. Why not just use that?